# Two MdPaginators for one Md-Table

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am working on creating an md-table for an application.  I can sort and paginate but need to add a paginator on the bottom as well as the top.  They should literally clone each other in functionality.  I've tried to create a second MdPaginator and then reference the first.

For example

```
@ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MdPaginator;
@ViewChild('paginator2') paginator2: MdPaginator;
```

Then I set

```
this.paginator2 = this.paginator
```

This is in hopes to get them to link together.  As mentioned, I have everything working just need a top and bottom paginator that are connected.

Comment: It's very uncommon case. Anyway, if I were you, I'd create a service and share the input values between the paginatorS.

Comment: I'm not sure that this use case is that uncommon.  It is nice to have a paginator at the bottom of a table and also at the top.  If a table list gets too long makes it a poor user experience to scroll all the way down, paginate and then back to the top.  Of course, this could be flipped, but either way the extraneous scrolling is a poor user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I finally developed a solution to this issue.  To achieve this behavior, I created an array of observables that I could pass to the class that extends cdk DataSource.  Next, I created a Subject that would be added to the array and be fired off when one of the paginators page events occurred.  I ended up subscribing to paginatorOne.page event and paginatorTwo.page event and synced up the pageIndex on these paginators then the Subject I created I fired that event by using .next(pageEvent).  Hope this helps anyone else trying to achieve this.